# Infinite matrices from $\ell^p$ to $\ell^{p/(p-1)}$ that are compact operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, infinite-sequences

I wanted to ask if my proof (sketch) of the following statement is correct. Namely, let $p>1$ and define $q= \frac{p}{p-1}$ we are given an operator $K : \ell^{p} \rightarrow \ell^{q}$ defined as $x \mapsto \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{jk}x_k$ where $\sum_{j,k \in \mathbb{N}} a_{jk}^{q} < \infty$. In order to show that this map is compact, I wanted to proceed along the following steps

- Use reflexivity of $\ell^p$ to use $K$ compact iff $K$ maps weakly converging sequences to strongly converging ones.
- We find that the map $l_j (x) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_{jk}x_k$ is in $(\ell^p)^*$ since it is bounded
- Then for any weakly converging sequence, $x^k \rightarrow x$, we now we use that
  $$\Vert K(x^m - x) \Vert = \Big(\sum_{j\in \mathbb{N}} | l_j(x^m -x)|^{q}\Big)^{1/q}$$
  and can for every $\varepsilon > 0$ find $m$ (if necessary passing to a diagonal sequence) s.t for all $j \in \mathbb{N}$, $| l_j(x^m -x)| < \frac{\varepsilon}{2^j}$ by weak convergence of $x^m$.
- Now reinserting this estimate into the norm and get that our sequence converges in the norm.

Is this proof correct? (maybe when producing the estimate I wonder whether $| l_j(x^m -x)| < \varepsilon a_{jm}$ actually suffices which is definitely given?

Yes, I realise that a limit of finite ranked operators can do the trick here but is the specific proof I gave correct ?

Comment: Once you have estimated the norm of $K$ with $(\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^q)^{1/q}$ just approximate $K$ with $K_N$, this last having zeros for $i$ or $j$ larger than $N$. $K_N$ is compact and converges in norm to $K$.

Comment: Ok, (I knew this way works) but the proof I gave not possible then? Because I wanted to use the reflexivity in this argument.